# Setting up local virtual host on Macbook

Tags: web-development, apache-http-server

Trying to setup apache virtual host on my macbook pro for development.

Want to setup site so i can use the following url format.

http://example.local

This resolves to apache's default index.html.en, the one which say's "It works!"

However, when I use http://localhost/example, seems to load example's index file.

Any ideas?

This is my setup

copy of my /etc/hosts file

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       example.local
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
#::1            localhost
#fe60::1%lo0    localhost
```

copy of /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf file

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.local
  ServerAlias example.local
  DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents/example
  #DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory /Library/WebServer/Documents/example/>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have remove other vhost from the file to eliminate vhost clashing.

Thanks
Dinesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you uncommented the following line in your `httpd.conf` and restarted apache?

```
# Virtual hosts
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

This, as it looks includes the vhosts conf `httpd-vhosts.conf`.

Comment: Thanks. 

You were right, I needed to uncomment the line out in httpd.conf to include the vhost.conf. 

Should have realised. 

Thinking about it, the reason why http://localhost/example was resolvin, is that the example web app folder is in the Document Root of the main httpd.conf. i.e. 

In httpd.conf

DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"

From my understanding, 

when the user types - http://localhost/example 

apache will serve files from 

/Library/WebServer/Documents/example/

Thanks again.